How to use HTML in radiobutton choiceNames in r Shiny
I am trying to display Radiobutton choiceNames that were generated based on a text input.  The choiceNames include a Greek letter (beta) and two subscripts (the first one is a number and the second one is a letter, j).
I tried creating a HTML and pass it to choiceNames but the HTML code itself is displayed.
Screenshot of the result:

As I enter "A B C" into the textbox, the radio button should be displayed with a label like  β1j,  β2j, and β3j.  However, the raw HTML code is displayed for the choiceNames.
How do I fix this issue?
library(shiny) 

ui <- fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel( 
      
      textInput("Radio_Button_Choices", "Enter Radio Button Choices", ""),
      
      fluidRow(
             uiOutput('Select_Radio_Buttons')
          )
    ), 
    mainPanel( 
      
    ) 
  ) 
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  
  
  output$Select_Radio_Buttons <- renderUI({
    
    Radio_Button_selection <- unlist(strsplit(input$Radio_Button_Choices, "\\s+"))
    RadioButton_selection_label = NULL
    
    if (length(Radio_Button_selection) > 0) {
      for (x in 1:length(Radio_Button_selection)){
        tempBeta = paste0('&beta;','<sub>',x,'j</sub>')
        tempBeta = paste0('"<div>',tempBeta,'</div>"')
        RadioButton_selection_label = as.list(c(RadioButton_selection_label, HTML(tempBeta)))
      }
    
    radioButtons("Model_Radio_Buttons","Select an option",
                 choiceNames =  RadioButton_selection_label,
                 choiceValues = Radio_Button_selection)
  }
  })
  
} 


shinyApp(ui, server) 


Try using the output like this:
output$Select_Radio_Buttons <- renderUI({
    
    Radio_Button_selection <- unlist(strsplit(input$Radio_Button_Choices, "\\s+"))
    RadioButton_selection_label = NULL
    
    if (length(Radio_Button_selection) > 0) {
      RadioButton_selection_label <- list()
      for (x in 1:length(Radio_Button_selection)){
        tempBeta = paste0('&beta;','<sub>',x,'j</sub>')
        tempBeta = paste0('"<div>',tempBeta,'</div>"')
        RadioButton_selection_label[[x]] = HTML(tempBeta)
      }
      radioButtons("Model_Radio_Buttons","Select an option",
                   choiceNames =  RadioButton_selection_label,
                   choiceValues = Radio_Button_selection)
    }
  })

I think the problem was using c() to add to the list. I guess that coerced the HTML() elements to strings? Anyway, with this method each list element stays a HTML() object which can be rendered properly in choiceNames.

It works! Thank you very much.  (I had to remove double quotes within tempBeta HTML.)
